# configure gnome-terminal using a configuration file rather than command line arguments

Tags: gnome-terminal

I've found in the gnome-terminal help documentation a really cool list of things you can configure in a file but absolutely no documentation of what the variables in the conf file are. I've googled a bunch for this and haven't found anything useful. Can someone point me to something or even list the actual commands. Or maybe come out and sit here at my desk and pair on it. My google-fu has failed me this morning.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not just talking about using gconf-editor (from the System menu usually) are you?

Actually, gconf-editor needs to be started from a terminal on my Ubuntu system here, but there are a bunch of settings under gnome-terminal there.

Comment: I don't seem to have gconf-editor on my centos installation. I wishwishwish I'd gone the Ubuntu route in the first place. I'll look for the tool and try and get it installed. thanks!

Comment: OK that got me a long way. I still need to find a list of valid key/values but I bet my googlish skills can handle that...thanks and have a green checkmark!

Answer (score 3):

Also, gconf-editor stores it's configurations for gnome-terminal in ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, there is no `gnome-terminal` directory within `~/.gconf/apps`, although I changed the settings

Answer (score 3):

GNOME Terminal has since changed how it stores its configuration; it now uses `dconf`, at least as of `gnome-terminal 3.28.2`.

You can query the `dconf` database for the UUIDs of available Profiles using:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list
```

Example output:

```
['b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9']
```

You can view all per-Profile configurable settings (called "keys" in `dconf`) and their current values using:

```
gsettings list-recursively "org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/"
```

Example output:

```
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile audible-bell false
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile cursor-shape 'block'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile cursor-colors-set true
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile scroll-on-keystroke true
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile cjk-utf8-ambiguous-width 'narrow'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile default-size-rows 24
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile encoding 'UTF-8'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile use-theme-colors false
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile custom-command ''
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile visible-name 'Unnamed'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile text-blink-mode 'always'

... lots more ...
```

(tip: you can sort alphabetically by key if you pipe to `sort`, so modify your command to `gsettings list-recursively "org.gnome......" | sort -k2`)

To set a key (e.g. `audible-bell`), use:

```
gsettings set \
    "org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/" \
    "audible-bell" \
    false
```

---

Check out [this script](https://github.com/villapx/home/blob/main/.local/bin/configure-gnome-terminal.sh) in my GitHub dotfiles repo for a practical example. In that script, I create a Profile of my own (if it does not already exist), set that Profile as the default, then configure the keys for that Profile as well as some global keys that apply to all profiles.